# how to add a custom select form element in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, select

i have a simple form with a select menu:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupAddItem">
        <select name="select-choice" data-native-menu="false">
            <option>Select an option</option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <a href="#popupAddItem" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Add Item</a>
</div>
```

i added `data-native-menu="false"` so that the drop down will look nicer, but it seems not to work if the form is inside a popup.

so if i remove `data-role="popup"` then the custom select element seems to work, else not.

Is this a bug, or am i doing something wrong? see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/KkJqn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that a custom select menu rendered as a popup itself and popups in jQM cannot be chained.

You can achieve similar effect using a jQM modal dialog instead of a popup.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <a href="#popupAddItem" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Add Item</a>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="popupAddItem">
        <div data-role="content">
        <select name="select-choice" data-native-menu="false">
            <option>Select an option</option>
            <option value="a">A</option>
        </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/a7hRR/)